# Compare two tables for common string and Add its ID to second table

Tags: sql-server, ssis

[image]I want to do this in SSIS. My situation is a s follows.I have Supplier table and a table which has the supplier/product name and other details about the products. Both the table have a common column called SupplierName. Now I want to compare these two columns and if they are same then insert the ID from the Supplier Table into this second table where all are in one table.

Comment: if you are using sql server 2008 then you can use Merge.refer this,
https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/the-merge-statement-in-sql-server-2008/

Comment: @KumarHarsh
thanks for your comments. How also want to not add the records which don't have matching names

Comment: it depend upon your query.unwanted record won't be added.show your query

Comment: `MERGE product p

USING Supplier s

ON p.supplierid = s.id

WHEN MATCHED THEN

 UPDATE

SET p.sectionID = s.id;`

I get this error Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The MERGE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FKED8DCCEF59E39C5". The conflict occurred in database "kaizenweb", table "dbo.Section", column 'id'.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Are the tables on the same server? If so you should go back to basics and write a single UPDATE statement to do this. It is not necessary to complicate the issue with an SSIS package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Lookup transformation.
You can lookup Supplier table from Product table based on Supplier Name and select Supplier ID as output.
This will add SupplierID along with other columns of Product table to the data pipeline.

Comment: I tried using LookupTransformation but I get error. Please see the image I have attached.you need to save the image on your computer to see it clearly the error I get.please help

Comment: This may be happening because there are no matching rows in your lookup table based on the columns you have selected for lookup. You can resolve it by selecting "Redirect rows to no match output" under the dropdown for "Specify how to handlerows with no matching entries" in General tab of Lookup transformation window. On a side note, do check if you are looking up to the correct column if you expect some matching data between the two tables.